# How to make a distribution curve for any data set including floating number in domain

Tags: matlab, histogram, distribution

I want to make a distribution curve for `X=[0 0 1.1 1.3 1.4 2.7 2.7 3.1 3.4 5.4 5.3 5.4]`

Whenever I try to do this using `hist()`, as you know it can only draw in an interval.

But I want to graph, say, when `x=0`, its frequency 2 is dotted in the figure

Answer (score 1):

```
%Define centers for the intervals, to let each value get it's own interval
C=sort(unique(X))
%accumulate data
[a,b]=hist(X,C);
%Plot with bar, because it looks better
bar(b,a);
```